# Add annotation from another data set at the top of bar plot by ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotations

I create a ggplot with the R code below. I would like to add the annotation from the data set evaluate to the bar plot. The annotations are supposed to present at the top of the bar for each school.  For example, for school A, the first annotation should be good, the second annotation should be open, the second annotation is under the first annotation. I tried gem_text, while it didn't work.

```
school <- c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C")
satisify <- c("yes","yes","no","no","no","yes","no","no","yes")
evaluate <-as.data.frame(cbind(c("A","B","C"),c("good","terrible","terrible"),c("open","close","close")))
colnames(evaluate) <- c("school","evaluate","decision")

data <- as.data.frame(cbind(school, satisify))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data,aes(x=school,fill=satisify))+geom_bar(aes(group=satisify, y=..prop..),position="dodge")
```

Comment: Can you explain more about how " the second annotation is under the first annotation"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you had in mind?

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>%
  count(satisify, school) %>%
  group_by(satisify) %>%
  mutate(prop = n / sum(n)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  left_join(evaluate) %>%
  ggplot(aes(school, prop, fill = satisify, group = satisify)) + 
  geom_col(position = position_dodge()) +
  geom_text(aes(label = evaluate), position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), vjust = -0.3) +
  geom_text(aes(label = decision), position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), vjust = 1.3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, this is a very convoluted method but works (?).

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  count(school, satisify) %>%
  group_by(satisify) %>%
  mutate(n = prop.table(n)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  left_join(evaluate, by = 'school') %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(evaluate, decision)) %>%
  group_by(school) %>%
  slice(1, n()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=school, y= n, fill=satisify, group = satisify, label = value)) + 
  geom_col(position = 'dodge') + 
  geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), vjust = -0.5)
```

[image]